# Update price of item before adding to cart!

Tags: price, custom, addtocart, customer-account

Just like the title says I want to change the price of the item before it hits the cart.  A customer configures an item before purchasing and different combinations equal different prices.  As a result I need to change the price of that specific (red shirt) not all red shirts!  Which should be related to quote item I believe.

I have a variable constantly updating that represents the new price while they are configuring their item.  Is there a way to pass this variable if it's stored in an ID and update the price for that quote item to the value of that ID before adding to the cart?

Let me know if there is anything I can clarify!
Similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048776/how-to-change-the-price-before-adding-to-cart-in-magento

But I want to use the variable I have and set the price to that!

Comment: You are use the configurable product ?

Comment: I use configurable products but we add simple ones to the cart, so I would be adding simple products with updated prices to the cart

Answer (score 2):

Create observer and implement below code:

Xml File
etc/config.xml

```
 <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <setadiscountprice>
                    <class>vendorName_PackageName_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>modifyPrice</method>
                </setadiscountprice>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
```

Php File :
 Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
    class vendorName_PackageName_Model_Observer
    {
        public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs ){
        // Get the quote item

            $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
            $product_id=$item->getProductId();
            $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $newprice=$_product->getPrice()+rand(10,100);

            Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');

            // Set the custom price
            $item->setCustomPrice($newprice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes great. Correct & working one :)  Thank you.